# How make doctrine findby to json field without native query

Tags: php, json, doctrine-orm

I use `json` column in `doctrine 2` (In `MySQL` database).
Actually, I made my search in `json` with native query like

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($entityManager);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata(\blabla\MyObject::class, 'o');
$query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery('select o.* from my_objects o where json_extract(jsonData, "$.test.key1")= "value1"', $rsm); 
//jsonData column contains {"test": {"key1" : "value1"}}
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Is it possible the made query like that without the native query mechanism ?
(like a findBy)

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I solved my problem using DQL extension
[scienta/doctrine-json-functions](https://github.com/SyslogicNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions)

Install it

```
composer req scienta/doctrine-json-functions
```

Usage

```
$queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $queryBuilder
    ->select("o")
    ->from(\bla\bla\MyObject::class, "o")
    ->where("JSON_EXTRACT(o.jsonData, :jsonPath) = :value ")
    ->setParameter('jsonPath', '$.test.key1')
    ->setParameter('value', 'value1')
    ->getQuery();

$co = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. i really needed to see this, it helped me out a lot

Answer (score 6):

I was just facing the same problem, but didn't want to install an additional extension. The code snippet from the original question just needs a small enhancement to work:

```
$rsm = $this->createResultSetMappingBuilder('n');
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata(MyObject::class, 'n');
$rawQuery = sprintf('SELECT %s FROM my_objects n WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(current_state, \'$.processing\')', $rsm->generateSelectClause());
$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($rawQuery, $rsm);
return $query->getResult();
```

And it works like a charm.

Comment: In which context do you use `$this`? @David used `$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($entityManager);` instead.

Comment: I use the code snippet in a repository class. This is where the $this came from. I forgot to mention that.