# Doctrine findBy type="json"

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

Can I query db by roles?

In database i have column roles type json and store data like this
["ROLE_ADMIN"]

How can i query via doctrine? I use this code down and don't work.

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findBy(['roles' => 'ROLE_ADMIN');
```

Comment: What's the error you get with that code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FOS bundle - How to select users with a specific role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016914/fos-bundle-how-to-select-users-with-a-specific-role)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776983/how-make-doctrine-findby-to-json-field-without-native-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `UserRepository` create a method which uses a `like` statement to find a user by role. Like this for example:

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findUsersByRole($role)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
        $qb->select('u')
            ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles')
            ->setParameter('roles', '%"'.$role.'"%');

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```